# A custom unordered list bullets doesn't works in the Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I use the following CSS to set the tick character (✓) as a bullet in an unordered list item:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul li:before
{
    content: '\2713';
    margin: 0 1em; 
    color:#E8001F;
}
```

It works perfectly fine on the Firefox 30.0 but the IE 9 shows no bullet at all.

My HTML is simply 
`<ul><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul>`

EDIT:

The reason why custom bullets didn't work is **IE in quirks mode** doesn't support given CSS. If we add

```
<!doctype html>
```

IE should switch to an another mode but in my case it's inappropriate. **The solution is usage of the image bullet.**

Comment: Try adding a display: inline-block; to the pseudo selector.

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile. If it's not been answered when I am on desktop I'll look into it properly. It's just pseudo content requires a display declaration to work.

Comment: Seemed to work for me, are you able to create a fiddle replicating the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with an image

```
li {
  list-style-image: url(image);
}
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code and its works in IE 9...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test List</title>
<style>
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul li:before
{
    content: '\2713';
    margin: 0 1em; 
    color:#E8001F;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtj8r.png